# GIF management on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, gif

I hate to ask what seems like something that could be Googled but I can't really find much and WP forums and such just tell me to re-size my GIFs.

I have a sports site and after events I like to post GIFs in my articles, the problem is they end up being about 4-7mb per GIF usually and I usually have about 10 of them. This obviously isn't very user friendly for some people and mobile, so I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to manage these things.

My current visitors love the GIFs but I don't want to discourage new people from using the site.

Comment: You mean animated GIFs?

Comment: Yes, made from video. Sorry I forgot to clarify.

Comment: Hmm, what kind of solution are you looking for? I can't think of any way except resizing (or re-encoding into a video which seems kinda pointless, though) Would you be happy not displaying them to mobile users?

Comment: I was thinking something like: They can see it, but it doesn't load until they click it or hover it perhaps?

Comment: If you have long pages, there's this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lazy-load/  - not 100% a solution to your problem though. I'm not aware of a ready-made solution that lazy loads on hover, although it should be relatively easy to do in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this until I can come across another solution. The pages are quite long because they are news/coverage articles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried photoshop to optimize them?
http://www.digitalfamily.com/tutorials/optimizing-images-in-gif-and-png-formats/

What you could do is use create two different image sizes one for mobile and one for desktop and then using css media queries you can change them.

```
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-    device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
  .mobile-only {background: url('your-image.gif');
}
```